# How to prove an isomorphism

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\Lambda$ be an artin algebra. Assume that $P$ is a projective left $\Lambda-$module,  $\Gamma=End_{\Lambda}(P)^{op}$, and $X, Y$ are two left $\Lambda-$modules.

If the projective cover of $X$ is in $add(P)$ and the injective envelope of $Y$ is in $add(\nu(P))$, where $add(M)$, for an arbitrary $\Lambda-$module $M$, is the full subcategory of $\text{mod}-\Lambda$ consisting of all modules isomorphic to summands of finite direct sums of $M$, and $\nu$ is the Nakayama functor.

How to prove the map 
$$Hom_{\Lambda}(X,Y)\rightarrow Hom_{\Gamma}(Hom_{\Lambda}(P,X),Hom_{\Lambda}(P,Y))$$
induced by $Hom_{\Lambda}(P,-)$ is an isomorphism?